# I need help fixing an unclaimed ethernet controller

Tags: drivers, internet, ethernet, realtek

I'm new to ubuntu. I have ubuntu 18.04
It has been fun so far, but I have no internet.

I used sudo lshw -c network and it says I have a Realtek rtl8111/8168/8411 pci express gigabit ethernet controller.
It is unclaimed.

How do I install a driver to make my ubuntu laptop have internet?

Comment: I thought I would just type sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms. But it makes a bunch of text and says building initial module for 4.15.0-20-generic and then it just sits there.

Comment: Did you perform a `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` before installing the dkms module?

Comment: No, it can't fetch ubuntu.com. I'll try giving it a wired connection and do that.

Comment: Update: I did that, and nothing changes. the terminal just says building initial module for 4.15.0-20-generic and doesn't do anything but sit there.